# Changing DICOM tags being read from a text file

Tags: java, dicom, dcm4che

I am working on a project that will potentially change `DICOM` tags in a `DCM` file based on tags that are read from a text file. I have searched the web for examples of changing DICOM tags in Java using the `dcm4chee` library, but find a very limited number of samples.

Can anyone advise if something like this is possible and if so if they happen to know of an example they can provide me with that shows of changing or inserting DICOM tags in *java*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working on this project, I found a way to modify/create tags in a dicom file that will be read from a text file.

Basically I added the tags found into the txt into an ArrayList. Once this was done, I looped through the list like this and was able to replace the tags by matching them with the putString(arg1,arg2,arg3) method found in `dcm4chee`:

```
            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            {
                String replaceTag = list.get(i).toString().replaceAll("[(),]", "");
                int valueofReplaceTag = (int)Long.parseUnsignedLong(replaceTag, 16);
                if(dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag).equals(VR.DA))
                    {
                        dcmObj.putString(valueofReplaceTag, dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag), "20150101");
                    }
                    else if(dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag).equals(VR.DT))
                    {
                        dcmObj.putString(valueofReplaceTag, dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag), "20150101");
                    }
            }
```